# Disable style (mat-expansion-panel)

Tags: html, css, angular-material

How to hide this `mat-expansion-panel` background when its disabled?

I have add this css

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-header[aria-disabled=true] {
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.26) !important;
color: rgb(107, 190, 198) !important;}
```

but its turn like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2VR3.png)

I also have trying inspect element from browser and find a class

```
.mat-expansion-panel {
background: #fff;
color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);}
```

When i try uncheck the "background" the white background its gone, but i dont know what i must to do in the css

Comment: can you show me the full HTML structure of the mat-expansion-panel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background is added by `mat-expansion-panel` which is the parent of the `.mat-expansion-panel-header`. So you want to change parent styles depending on an attribute ( `aria-disabled` ) of the child.

This is not possible with css.

What you might do is setting the `.mat-expansion-panel` ( parent ) background-color to transparent as default. So overwrite the initial values. And add `background-color:#fff` to the `panel-header` instead. And then overwrite that when it's disabled.

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel{
    background: transparent;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* transparent */
}
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-header{
    /* styles that were added to panel before */
    background: #fff;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87); 
}


::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-header[aria-disabled=true] {
    /* change what you want */
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.26);
    color: rgb(107, 190, 198);
}
```

Comment: thank you,, its hide the white background, but now i have issue with the active class.. :D

Comment: what issue? :))

Comment: sory for replying so late, its make the active class also hide its white background :)))

Comment: nvm, im already do some trick for it. thank you so much... xD